# How to cancel a request using a workbox plugin

Tags: workbox

Within our project we developed some custom workbox plugins (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/using-plugins/) which, for example, add additional headers to a request handled by a certain rule. Example:

```
registerRoute(
    new RegExp('example.com'),
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'auxiliary-data',
        plugins: [
            new DoSomethingPlugin(),
            new DoSoemthingElsePlugin(),
        ],
    }),
);
```

Currently, we want to build a plugin which can decide whether a request should be made at all. So the plugin should be able to cancel a request. We found that it is possible to just replace the `Request` object by something else (which is invalid, like `Request('')`) and cancel it that way. However, I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to it. Any ideas?